# Graph API - User table - column tv

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying getting data of the column tv of the user table using the following code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=tv&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&format=json
```

Result is:

```
 "message": "Unknown fields: tv"
```

Other fields such as: movie,music,books, etc running OK.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tv` is its name in the `user` FQL [table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/), while in the graph API the connection is called [`television`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) (live [example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=television)):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=television
```

Comment: Great. Facebook have a bad documentation.
Thanks.